# How to make some virtual folders be served by iis while others are served by apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, asp.net, reverse-proxy

I have a site written in PHP and it is served by Apache installed on Linux. 
To say, its url is `example.com` and it has subfolders `audio`, `games`, `photo`, so user point to it as `example.com/photo`.

Now I'm writing new features (for example, ability to view films) in ASP.Net and would like it to be accessible by users as `example.com/video`. And IIS to serve it is istalled on another server which is not visible from internet (only Apache has straight access to internet) but it easily can be reached from apache through intranet.

User sessions are not important!

How should I configure it to work efficiently? Possibly I need to install some more software?

I posted my solution which as far as I understand is what **Farseeker** means, but I'd like to hear other advices if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gone and tagged the question "reverse-proxy", so you've got that much right :)

I take it that Apache is your default listener on :80 for your public IP? If this is the case, then you will need to configure Apache's `mod_proxy` module, and configure it to rewrite requests for `example.com/video` to `IISSERVER/video`

If your default listener is IIS, then the idea is the same, but you will need to use a commercial product like [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) to do this.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your reply and I close question because I didn't het any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache is the default listener on public ip on 80 port.
I used `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` adding in virtualhost following lines:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /video http://iis_ip:iis_port
ProxyPassReverse /video http://iis_ip:iis_port
```

But I'm in doubt that I chose best solution. One of the alternatives I see is to install ngin and make it default. Then forward requests from nginx to Apacge and IIS.Maybe there other variants, so I don't close question yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here, so I can't vote-up Farseeker's answer. But that does the trick - Apache reverseproxy *is* what you're asking for. You can use many different products to do this, but given what you've said that you have, that's probably the best answer.

Comment: As far as I understand that is what I've done, yes? I described it in my answer

Comment: Welcome mfinni, enjoy your stay!

Comment: Flashnik - yes, you said you'd done that, and then said you don't think you picked the best solution. Until/unless you describe what you want, that mod_proxy is lacking, we can't give you a better suggestion.

Comment: Well, I meant that I'm not sure that it is the best solution. I'm new to web development since before I had a background only in a desktop programming.